# Must a function be convex to be polyconvex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{M}^{3\times3}$ denote the set of real $3\times3$ matrices and $\boldsymbol F \in \mathbb{M}$ with $\det \boldsymbol F > 0$.

Given a function $W(\boldsymbol F) = P(\boldsymbol F, \det \boldsymbol F) = \frac{\lVert \boldsymbol F \rVert^2}{(\det \boldsymbol F)^{2/3}}$, where $\lVert F \rVert$ is the Frobenius norm of $\boldsymbol F$.

I know that $W(\boldsymbol F)$ is polyconvex, which is defined as

---

[image]

---

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyconvex_function for a slightly differently formulated definition

I am looking for a methodology how to show polyconvexity for a given function $P(\boldsymbol F, \mathrm{adj} \boldsymbol F, \det \boldsymbol F)$.
Based on my understanding of polyconvexity, I have to show that $P$ is a convex function, right? To do so, the Hessian matrix of second derivatives must be positive semidefinite.
However, polyconvexity is a weaker property than convexity. That said, how can I check for polyconvexity?

Comment: @user1551 Why is the domain of $f$ not convex?

Comment: @Simon When you said "non symmetric", did you perhaps mean "not necessarily symmetric"?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Yes, not necessarily symmetric. I updated the question. Now, the domain of $f$ is convex, right?

Comment: @user1551 the matrix F comes from a physical application and det(F) is always positive and F is in general not symmetric. I do not know how to translate this in mathematical terms.

Comment: @user1551 Ah right, I forgot to think about that part...

Comment: @Simon As mentioned by user1551, the question as it is now doesn't quite make sense mathematically. Since you said the question actually comes from physics, perhaps you can describe what exactly you are looking for? Maybe convexity isn't really the thing you want.

Comment: @user1551 Actually, I want to show that $f$ is polyconvex, which is a weaker property than convexity as described in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyconvex_function

Comment: @BigbearZzz I am looking for polyconvexity of $f$, which is described in https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polykonvexe_Funktion and also the link in the previous comment.

Comment: @Simon You should edit the question to polyconvexity, then.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I updated my question. Can you help me as for polyconvexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition, a function $W\colon \Bbb R^{N\times n} \to \Bbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is *polyconvex* if $W$ is a convex function of all the subdeterminants (minors) of its argument. In particular, in the case $n=N=3$ the subdeterminants of a $3\times 3$ matrix $\mathbf A$ are either the entries of $\mathbf A$ itself, the entries of $\text{cof}\, \mathbf A$, or $\det \mathbf A$. Hence $W$ is polyconvex if and only if there exists a convex function $P\colon \Bbb R^{(3\times 3)+(3\times 3)+1}\to \Bbb R\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that
$$
W(\mathbf A) = P(\mathbf A, \text{cof}\, \mathbf A,\det \mathbf A).
$$

Now, in your question we have
$$
P(\mathbf A,\mathbf B,y) = \frac{|\mathbf A|^2}{y^{2/3}} = H\left(g(\mathbf A,\mathbf B,y)\right),
$$
where $g\colon\Bbb R^{(3\times 3)+(3\times 3)+1}\to \Bbb R^{(3\times3)+1}$ and $H\colon \Bbb R^{3\times 3}\times(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ are defined by
$$
g(\mathbf A,\mathbf B,y) = (\mathbf A,y)
$$
and
$$
H(\mathbf A,y) = \frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^3 a_{ij}^2}{y^{2/3}},
$$
where, of course, $a_{ij}$'s are the entries of $\mathbf A$. I am just trying to be very explicit here by mentioning the affine map $g$ which is just a projection that kills the term $\mathbf B$. It simply means that our $W$ doesn't depend on the cofactors and we can thus replace $P$ with $H$, i.e.
$$
W(\mathbf A) = H(\mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)
$$
and the polyconvexity of $W$ depends only on the convexity of $H\colon \Bbb R^{3\times 3}\times(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ (since $g$ is affine).

It is not hard to see that $g(\mathbf A, \text{cof}\, \mathbf A,\det \mathbf A) = (\mathbf A,\det \mathbf A) \in \Bbb R^{3\times 3}\times(0,\infty)$ whenever $\mathbf A \in \Bbb M^{3\times 3}$. Now you only have to check that $H$ is convex on its domain $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}\times(0,\infty)$.

---

**Edit:** Added details on how to prove that $H(\mathbf A,y)$ is convex.

It is easy to see that $H(\mathbf A,y) = \tilde H(f_1(\mathbf A), f_2(y))$ on the domain of $\tilde H$, where $\tilde H\colon [0,\infty) \times (0,\infty) \to \Bbb R , f_1\colon \Bbb R^{3 \times 3} \to [0,\infty), f_2\colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ are defined as
$$
\tilde H(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y^{2/3}},\ \  f_1(\mathbf A) = |\mathbf A|,\ \  \text{ and } f_2(y) = y.
$$

It is enough that we prove the following "composition theorem" to show that $H$ is convex.

> *Theorem:* Let $I_1, I_2$ be two intervals in $\Bbb R$, $\tilde F\colon I_1 \times I_2 \to \Bbb R$ is a function, let $V_1, V_2$ be vector spaces and $C_j \subset V_j$ be their convex subsets. Consider the composition
> $$
> F(u_1, u_2) = \tilde F(f_1(u_1), f_2(u_2)),
> $$
> where $f_j \colon C_j \to I_j$, then $F\colon C_1 \times C_2 \to \Bbb R$ is convex if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\tilde F$ is convex on its domain and is increasing in its first variable, i.e. for any $y\in I_2$ we have $\tilde F(x_1,y) \le \tilde F(x_2,y)$ whenever $x_1 \le x_2$.
> 2. $f_1$ is a convex function.
> 3. $f_2$ is an affine function ($f_2((1-t)u + tv) = (1-t)f_2(u) + tf_2(v)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$).

*Proof:* Let $u_1, v_1 \in C_1$ and $u_2, v_2 \in C_2$, then for any $t\in [0,1]$ we have
$$\begin{align}
F((1-t)(u_1,u_2) + t(v_1,v_2)) &= F((1-t)u_1 + tv_1, (1-t)u_2 + tv_2) \\
&= \tilde F(f_1((1-t)u_1 + tv_1), f_2((1-t)u_2 + tv_2)) \\
&\le \tilde F((1-t)f_1(u_1) + tf_1(v_1), f_2((1-t)u_2 + tv_2)).
\end{align}$$
Here we used that fact that $f_1$ is convex and $\tilde F$ is increasing in the first variable. Now, since $f_2$ is affine, the expression on the last line is equal to
$$
\tilde F((1-t)f_1(u_1) + tf_1(v_1), (1-t)f_2(u) + tf_2(v))
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\tilde F((1-t)(f_1(u_1), f_2(u_2)) + t(f_1(v_1), f_2(v_2)) ). 
$$
We know that
$$\begin{align}
\tilde F((1-t)(f_1(u_1), f_2(u_2)) &+ t(f_1(v_1), f_2(v_2)) ) \\ &\le (1-t)\tilde F((f_1(u_1), f_2(u_2)) + t \tilde F((f_1(v_1), f_2(v_2)) \\
&= (1-t)F(u_1,u_2) + tF(v_1,v_2)
\end{align}$$
by the convexity of $\tilde F$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. To check that $H$ is convex on its domain, its Hessian matrix must be positive semidefinite on the domain. Is that true?

Comment: @Simon That's a sufficient condition to guarantee convexity, yes. We can do that in this case.

Comment: @Simon Another alternative would be to consider the restriction of $H$ on a segment between the points, say, $(\mathbf A, y)$ and $(\mathbf B, z)$ in the domain. In this case, we prove that the function $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
f(t) = H((1-t)\mathbf A+t\mathbf B, (1-t)y+tz)
$$
is convex. You can take the second derivative of $f$ and show that it is positive, for example.

Comment: This brings me back to what I posted originally: The function $\tilde{H}(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y^{2/3}}$
with $x=\lVert \boldsymbol F \rVert$ and $y= \det \boldsymbol F$ is convex. From this, can I conclude that $H(\boldsymbol F, \det \boldsymbol F)$ is convex as well (because the frobenius norm is convex)?

Comment: @Simon In this case there is a way to make that line of argument work, but it isn't as direct as you would hope. Generally, the composition of 2 convex functions need not be convex (the usual method to make this work is to require that both functions be real-valued and one of them is increasing), let alone the fact that $(\mathbf A, x) \mapsto (|| \mathbf A||, x)$ is vector-valued. I wrote my answer in a way that I believe would make it simpler for you to finish the proof. Pursuing your line of reasoning, while more interesting, would potentially lead to confusion and misunderstanding imo.

Comment: This would make my life a lot easier because then the Hessian is 2x2. You said, there is a way to make that line of argument work. From an engineering viewpoint, I am not interested in a deep mathematical explanation. The fact that is is true would be sufficient for me.

Comment: @Simon The difficult part would be the kind of composition theorem that you need to prove in order to draw such a conclusion. By the way, the Hessian of $H$ takes quite a simple form, not that much different than your  $\tilde H$. While of the size $10 \times 10$, there's an obvious pattern that can be exploit. You should try to do the calculation first.

Comment: Does such a composition theorem that we would need here already exist? The pattern of the Hessian may be simple in this example, but my "real" $H$ looks different. Also, my $H$ has some parameters that are to be adjusted to make $H$ convex. Deriving those constraints from a 10x10 Hessian is more difficult than from a 2x2 Hessian.

Comment: @Simon Not to my knowledge, I can't think of a single theorem that allows you to conclude what you want from the mere fact that both the Frobenius norm and $\tilde H$ is convex. The way I'm thinking of requires one to show that  $\tilde H$ has a stronger property than just being convex, thus being able to compute the Hessian of  $\tilde H$ wouldn't help. I won't try to stop you from pursuing your method though, I am just warning you that it isn't as simple as you think.

Comment: @Simon There are some nice characterizations of polyconvex functions with high symmetry, which works for this case and perhaps also works for similar cases that might be of your interest. You can look at Dacorogna's "Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations (2nd edition)", in particular chapter 5.3.4. This isn't the same as your suggested approach though.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. What nice characterizations do you mean in particular that work for the example of my question?

Comment: @Simon Yes, it works for this particular question and even more general ones. As I mentioned, for this question there is a way to make your approach work, but I don't know if this would generalize to other questions that you are interested in. Your $\tilde H(x,y)$ is increasing in the $x$ variable, which is sufficient for this purpose and the proof just for this case would be quite simple (look for the proof of the scalar case). It all depends on how general you want your decomposition theorem to be, but as I said, $\tilde H$ being convex alone is far from enough.

Comment: So $H(F, \det F)$ in my question is convex ifI show that $\tilde{H}(\lVert F \rVert , \det F)$ is convex? You said the proof is quite simple. If you have the time for it, would you extend your answer to show this? I mean, I can show that both $H$ and $\tilde{H}$ are convex, but I want the statement: $\tilde{H}$ convex -> $H$ convex (just here).

Comment: @Simon I have just edited the answer to include the proof of a composition theorem that is good enough for $\tilde H$.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time! I have two questions: First, if  you write $F((1-t)(u_1,u_2)+t(v_1,v_2)) = F((1-t)u_1+tv_1, (1-t)u_2+tv_2))$, this means that the left side is just an abbreviation of the right side or, in other words, the right side is a different way of writing down the left side? Second: "Here we used that fact that $f_1$ is convex and $\tilde{F}$ is increasing in the first variable"... I can only see that you applied the convexity of $f_1$ when gooing from the second line $=...$ to the third $\leq ...$. What do I miss here?

Comment: @Simon For the first question, yes. It's just 2 different ways of writing the same thing. For the second one, convexity of $f$ gives $f((1-t)x+ty) \le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$, but it's not true that $\Phi(f((1-t)x+ty)) \le \Phi((1-t)f(x)+tf(y))$ as well. For that, we need $\Phi$ to be increasing.

Comment: Makes sense. It is easy to see that 1., 2., 3. are fulfilled here. To show the convexity of $H(\boldsymbol A , \det \boldsymbol A)$ based on a generic $\tilde{H}(f_1(\boldsymbol A), f_2(\det \boldsymbol A))$, I will always choose $f_1(\boldsymbol A) = \lVert \boldsymbol A \rVert$ and $f_2(\det \boldsymbol A) = \det \boldsymbol A$. That said, 2. and 3. are always satisfied and what I have to show is 1., right?

Comment: @Simon Just to be clear here, you would be correct in saying that the convexity of $H(\mathbf A, y) = \tilde H(||\mathbf A||, y)$ can be proved by showing that $\tilde H$, $f_1(\mathbf A) = ||A||$ and $f_2(y) = y$ satisty all the above conditions. Here $f_1$ and $f_2$ already satisfy their respective conditions, so you only need to check $\tilde H$. Be careful with an expression like $H(\mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)$ since this can be easily confused as a function of $\mathbf A$, say $W(\mathbf A)$. It's better to say just $H$ or $H(\mathbf A, y)$.

Comment: Can we say that the fulfillment of the above theorem is a stronger condition than the convexity of $H$? Example: we know that if $H$ is convex, $H$ is also polyconvex, hence, in my literature there is often the phrase "the convexity is a stronger condition than polyconvexity."

Comment: @Simon You are misunderstanding the term, which is why I insist on writing $H$ as $H(\mathbf A,y)$ and not $H(\mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)$. That is because the later expression denotes another function of $\mathbf A$, namely $W(\mathbf A) = H(\mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)$ which is a composition of $H$ and the map $\mathbf A \mapsto (\mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)$. That phrase means that the convexity of $W$ is a stronger condition than $W$ being merely polyconvex. Proving that $H(\mathbf A, y)$ is convex implies that $W$ is polyconvex, but doesn't say anything about the convexity of $W$.

Comment: @Simon I implore that you read the first half of my answer again to help understanding the distinction. Recall the stored energy density $W(\mathbf A) = P(\mathbf A, \text{cof}\, \mathbf A,\det \mathbf A)$ (or in our case, $P$ is just $H$ as it doesn't depend on the cofactors), we wish to examine the convexity and polyconvexity "of $W$". Convexity (of $W$) is a great condition, but often not satisfied by many physical systems we might be interested in, so we settle for the next best thing which is showing that $W$ somehow retains some properties resembling convexity (to be continued)...

Comment: @Simon (continued) One popular condition that is good enough to replace the convexity (of $W$) and is satisfied by many real world examples is polyconvexity. $W$ is polyconvex if we can find an auxiliary function $P=P(\mathbf B, \mathbf C, z)$ such that $W$ is a composition of $P$ and $\mathbf A\mapsto (\mathbf A, \text{cof}\, \mathbf A, \det \mathbf A)$ **and** $P$ is a convex function. It doesn't make sense to talk about the polyconvexity of $P$, $P$ is an auxiliary function which, if exists and is convex, implies that $W$ has good properties.

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed mixing expressions up. Let me clarify what I want to do with all that here: $H(\boldsymbol A, y) = \tilde{H}(\lVert \boldsymbol A \rVert, y) = \sum\limits_{a=1}^n N_a(\lVert \boldsymbol A \rVert, y) E_a$, where $E_a \geq 0$ are real, positive numbers and $N_a$ are piecewise polynomials. Sloppy speaking, $\tilde{H}$ represents the interpoland of the discrete values $E_a$ and the $N_a$ are interpolation functions. The $E_a$ have to be determined via non-linear optimization and to work this properly, I must implement constraints so as that (W) is polyconvex...

Comment: (continued) To do so, I have to proove your derived theorem which basically boils down to show that $\tilde{H}$ is convex. Since the $N_a$ are not convex, I have to adjust the $E_a$ to make the Hessian positive semidefinite. At the end, I want to come up with linear or nonlinear constraints (e.g $c_1E_1 + \dots + c_nE_n$ > 0). However, this prooves to be quite tedious and I was wondering if you see a way to make this tractable. I would appreciate if you were willed to help me out further, I could open a new question then.

Comment: @Simon Indeed, it probably better to open a new question to ask so that you have more room to explain the details of what you want to do (and the comments chain here is getting too long for this site too). If you are satisfied with the answer to the question posted here, consider accepting it so that the question will be marked as "answered".

Comment: Yes, you really helped me. I would appreciate if you could have a look on my new question which is heavily based on this discussion here. Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718914/adjusting-numbers-to-make-a-scalar-function-of-two-variables-convex-on-its-domai